# Inside JSON nested array outpt using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, json

This is the JSON output i want

```
{
   "MainEvent":"Geelong v Essendon",
   "OutcomeDateTime":"2014-06-27 19:51:00.0000000",
   "Competitors":[
      {
         "Name":"Geelong",
         "Win":"1.32"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Essendon",
         "Win":"3.40"
      }
   ]
},
{
  "MainEvent":"Hawthorn v Gold Coast",
  "OutcomeDateTime":"2014-06-28 13:46:00.0000000",
   "Competitors":[
      {
         "Name":"Geedlong",
         "Win":"1.32d"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Essenddon",
         "Win":"3.40d"
      }
   ]
}
```

This  is my code

```
foreach ($SortedByDate as $key => $values){
    foreach ($json_a as $root_element => $childnode) {
        foreach( $childnode as $cKey => $subChild) {
            $rootObj = array(
                'MainEvent' => $subChild['MainEvent'], 
                'OutcomeDateTime' => $subChild['OutcomeDateTime'], 
                foreach($subChild['Competitors']['Competitors'] as $compKey => $compVal) {
                    $teamName = $compVal['Team'];
                    $win = $compVal['Win'];
                    $abc = array(
                        "Team" => $teamName,
                        "Win" => $win,
                    ); 
                }   
            } 
            $rootObj ['Competitors'] = $abc;  
        }} 
         $abc="";
        print json_encode($rootObj );
}
```

And i am getting this output . But comma is missing in my output. Can anyone give me some suggestions please?

```
  {
       "MainEvent":"Geelong v Essendon",
       "OutcomeDateTime":"2014-06-27 19:51:00.0000000",
       "Competitors":[
          {
             "Name":"Geelong",
             "Win":"1.32"
          },
          {
             "Name":"Essendon",
             "Win":"3.40"
          }
       ]
    }
    {
      "MainEvent":"Hawthorn v Gold Coast",
      "OutcomeDateTime":"2014-06-28 13:46:00.0000000",
       "Competitors":[
          {
             "Name":"Geedlong",
             "Win":"1.32d"
          },
          {
             "Name":"Essenddon",
             "Win":"3.40d"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I have tried these code but i am not sure how to add *comma* in my output JSON

Comment: The JSON output you want is not valid JSON.

Comment: before *{* which is above MainEvent element can you check the output

Comment: @MikeW i am missing Root which i am printing using echo ("Sports"); if you can suggest me better way to get this done then i would appreciate your efforts

Comment: You're replying to answers with other errors.  Your code above can't actually be running as you have posted it.  See the line `'OutcomeDateTime' => $subChild['OutcomeDateTime'],` -- I would think you want it to be `'OutcomeDateTime' => $subChild['OutcomeDateTime']);`  Something is varying between what you're running and what you're showing.

Comment: yes i edit my code and i just copied the relevant code from my code structure and i am not replying with any *new errors*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing it twice, it will not have comma;

Try this:

```
$jsons = array();
    foreach ($SortedByDate as $key => $values){
        foreach ($json_a as $root_element => $childnode) {
            foreach( $childnode as $cKey => $subChild) {
                $rootObj = array(
                    'MainEvent' => $subChild['MainEvent'], 
                    'OutcomeDateTime' => $subChild['OutcomeDateTime'], 
                    foreach($subChild['Competitors']['Competitors'] as $compKey => $compVal) {
                        $teamName = $compVal['Team'];
                        $win = $compVal['Win'];
                        $abc = array(
                            "Team" => $teamName,
                            "Win" => $win,
                        ); 
                    }   
                } 
                $rootObj ['Competitors'] = $abc;  
            }} 
             $abc="";
             $jsons[] = json_encode($rootObj);
    }
print implode(",",$jsons);
```

doesn't look like a valid JSON to me though

let me know if it works.

Comment: this one is not working i am getting error arse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the root objects in another array:

```
$rootObjects = [];
foreach ($SortedByDate as $key => $values){
    // ...
    $rootObjects[] = $rootObj;
}
echo json_encode($rootObjects);
```

It will output `[{object1}, {object2}, ....]`, i.e. the output includes two square brackets that weren't present in your expected output but are important to make it valid JSON.

Comment: @user3754380 well your code gives me a parse error =p